# how to get clipboard data to a variable in intersystems cache?

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

consider i have some data copied to my clip board. I would like to get those into a variable(**not in a way of pasting on terminal window**),so i can able to make use of that variable.
can any one suggest any way of doing it.either by using script execution or anything using class or etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will give more information about your application: WEB/ZEN/CSP, TUI, other types.
Anyway, Cache, do not have any special variables for clipboard.